# Using EXISTS as a column in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, exists

Is it possible to use the value of `EXISTS` as part of a query?

(*Please note*: unfortunately due to client constraints, I need SQLServer 2005 compatible answers!)

So when returning a set of results, one of the columns is a boolean value which states whether the subquery would return any rows.

For example, I want to return a list of usernames and whether a different table contains any rows for each user.  The following is not syntactically correct, but hopefully gives you an idea of what I mean...

```
SELECT T1.[UserName],
    (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM [AnotherTable] T2 
             WHERE T1.[UserName] = T2.[UserName])
    ) AS [RowsExist]
FROM [UserTable] T1
```

Where the resultant set contains a column called `[UserName]` and boolean column called `[RowsExist]`.

The obvious solution is to use a `CASE`, such as below, but I wondered if there was a better way of doing it...

```
SELECT T1.[UserName],
    (CASE (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM [AnotherTable] T2 
           WHERE T1.[UserName] = T2.[UserName]
          )
          WHEN 0 THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
          ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END
    ) AS [RowsExist]
FROM [UserTable] T1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query isn't valid syntax.

```
SELECT T1.[UserName],
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   [AnotherTable] T2
                      WHERE  T1.[UserName] = T2.[UserName]) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
         ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
       END AS [RowsExist]
FROM   [UserTable] T1
```

Is generally fine and will be implemented as a semi join.

The article [Subqueries in CASE Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx) discusses this further.

In some cases a `COUNT` query can actually perform better though [as discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46359/check-existence-with-exists-outperform-count-not/46361#46361)

Comment: Ack, yes, you're correct - sorry was typing off the top of my head.  Have added the missing `COUNT(*)`

Comment: I wasn't aware of `COUNT` being faster than `EXISTS` in certain situations...  will definitely bare that in mind.  Thank you.

Comment: `TOP 1 1` should be even faster ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - No it isn't. SQL Server is well aware that `EXISTS` only needs a single row. And there is no benefit of using the literal `1` compared to `*` either.

Comment: But how can `COUNT` be faster than `EXISTS` then, I mean for count you would have to pull every row, I dont understand

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - Did you read the answer I linked? In the particular case there using `EXISTS` in a `CASE` prevented a particular transformation meaning that unnecessary additional rows were read from the second table. The predicate `WHERE T1.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 7000` could also have been applied to `T2` to limit the number of `T2` rows read but wasn't in the `EXISTS` case.

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote here I would alter your first query into something like this

```
SELECT
        T1.[UserName], ISNULL(
            (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 1
                    FROM [AnotherTable]
                    WHERE EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT
                                    1
                                FROM [AnotherTable] AS T2
                                WHERE T1.[UserName] = T2.[UserName]
                        )
            ), 0)
    FROM [UserTable] T1
```

But actually if you use `TOP 1 1` you would not need `EXISTS`, you could also write

```
SELECT
        T1.[UserName], ISNULL(
            (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 1
                    FROM [AnotherTable] AS T2
                    WHERE T1.[UserName] = T2.[UserName]
            ), 0)
    FROM [UserTable] T1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, hadn't thought of the `TOP 1` way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

I like the other guys sql better but i just wrote this:

```
with bla as (
    select t2.username, isPresent=CAST(1 AS BIT)
    from t2
    group by t2.username
)
select t1.*, isPresent = isnull(bla.isPresent, CAST(0 AS BIT))
from t1 
    left join blah on t1.username=blah.username
```

Comment: I did wonder about CTE's, but my gut feeling is that it wouldn't be particularly good performance (but that is purely gut feeling without any proof).  Thanks for your input